# Sybase ASE data purge batch - identifying # of rows to delete in a transaction

Tags: batch-processing, sap-ase

We have multiple applications using Sybase ASE (currently migrating from 15.0 to 15.7). I am working on a generic utility that can be used by all of our ASE databases to purge unwanted old data. The utility is supposed to run at a specified window (12:00 to 3:00 AM) and can slowly keep deleting the data day-by-day without affecting other users or without bringing the database down. 
As multiple tables with different parameters are involved, I need to figure-out an optimal algorithm to decide the number of rows deleted in each transaction. 
 - Should the amount of data deleted be calculated using a formula based on user cache/ data cache/ log space/ some other param? If so, can you please mention a formula? 
 - For now, I am using the following brute force safety limit and looping through the delete query, committing at each loop traversal:

```
set rowcount 100
```

Additionally, do we have a way to consider the following parameters? If so, how much weightage should I give to each of these parameters?

1. Based on max row size of a table, dynamically fix the number of rows deleted?
2. Index:

   - If the deletion criteria matches an index, delete more rows in a tran (how many?)
   - If the deletion criteria matches an index, use "select for update" (ASE 15.7)
   - If there are other index not matching the given column criteria, should I "select into #temptbl" the index column values matching the input criteria and then do the deletes joining the #temptbl?
   - If there is no index at all, should I set the #of rows deleted with "set rowcount" using the table's max row size?

Comment: could someone help me with this?

Comment: Thanks for your comments Michael. I shall use "set rowcount 100" for now and once you provide some inputs, I can change it accordingly.